# Why do late answers appear in the First Posts review queue?

Tags: support, review, questions, answers

My understanding is that a "late answer" is a new user answering a question and a "first post" is a new user asking a question. If I'm correct why do late answers appear in the First Posts review queue on Pro Webmasters? Is there any reason behind this?

If I'm wrong what is the difference between a "first post" and a "late answer"?

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> and First Post means new user asking a question.

That's not true. Answers also go to the First Posts queue. And because a Late Answer by a new user is in most cases a First Post, so it goes to both queues.

Comment: Then whats the difference between First Post and Late Answer?

Comment: @SathiyaKumar In the Late Answers queue, you'll find new answers to old questions. In the First Posts queue, you'll see all first posts.